# Google Drive Spreadsheet export to CSV

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-drive-api, export-to-csv

Looks like Google has removed ability to export (publish to web) spreadsheets in CSV format. How can i do it now?

Answer (score 0):

Here's .Net version :

```
static string DownloadCsvUrl = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key={0}&gid={1}&exportFormat={2}";
Google.Apis.Download.MediaDownloader downloader = new Google.Apis.Download.MediaDownloader(SpreadsheetService);
var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
DownloadCsvUrl = String.Format(DownloadCsvUrl, spreadsheetId, worksheetId, format);
downloader.Download(DownloadCsvUrl, outputStream);
```

outputStream will have your csv data.

Easy :)